# ifelse 'unexpected symbol' error in R

Tags: r

Its just a basic ifelse but its returning the error: "unexpected symbol" and points to the first character of the last line.
any ideas?

```
input1<-readline("using C:/Users/HouseGroup/Desktop/betterformat.csv as the target csv file.
  Is this correct?  Y/N" )
ifelse (input1=="Y",
theData <- read.csv("C:/Users/HouseGroup/Desktop/betterformat.csv"),
rightDir<- readline("please input the proper file path") 
theData<-  read.csv(rightDir))
```

Comment: I don't think so...
"test" is input1=="Y"
"yes" is
     theData <-read.csv("C:/Users/HouseGroup/Desktop/betterformat.csv")
"no" is 
     rightDir<- readline("please input the proper file path") 
     theData<-  read.csv(rightDir)

Comment: Missing semicolon, then? You have to have something to separate the last two lines for the parser.

Comment: I've never used a semicolon in r, it just parses separate lines with just a return.
Tried it tho, semicolon doesn't work

Comment: Now that I look at this, I'm not even sure what you're intended this `ifelse` statement to do. It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: This is not what `ifelse` is for.  Use a regular `if` statement.

Comment: what is the difference in usage for ifelse and if...else?
I thought it was just a readability thing

Comment: That sounds like a question for the documentation...

Comment: `if (input1=="Y")
  theData <- read.csv("C:/Users/HouseGroup/Desktop/betterformat.csv")
else
{
  rightDir<- readline("please input the proper file path")
  theData<-  read.csv(rightDir)
}`
doesn't work either. Shows up as "unexpected else"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the standard `if` and `else` construct in R, as defined by the [R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#if).

> When the if statement is not in a block the else, if present, must
>   appear on the same line as the end of statement2. Otherwise the new
>   line at the end of statement2 completes the if and yields a
>   syntactically complete statement that is evaluated. A simple solution
>   is to use a compound statement wrapped in braces, putting the else on
>   the same line as the closing brace that marks the end of the statement

```
if (input1=="Y") {
  theData <- read.csv("C:/Users/HouseGroup/Desktop/betterformat.csv")
} else {
  rightDir <- readline("please input the proper file path") 
  theData <- read.csv(rightDir)
}
```

The command `ifelse` takes vectors and returns vectors. See `?ifelse` for examples.

```
x <- c(6:-4)
sqrt(x)  #- gives warning
sqrt(ifelse(x >= 0, x, NA))  # no warning
```

Comment: ok sweet. Before I saw your full solution I put braces around the entire last thing I posted and it works. Thanks! still wondering why the ifelse statement didn't work though, it was all within the ifelse(~~~~~)... weird

Comment: @hedgedandlevered Not weird at all. Like I alluded to above, there wasn't anything separating your final two lines for the parser. The reason the line break had no effect was because those two lines are being fed to the function `ifelse` as an argument, a single expression. Semicolons are (frequently) used in R to force such a separation. Try `a <- 3; b <- 2` on a single line.

Comment: @hedgedandlevered That said, I doubt that trying to re-call `readline` like that from within `ifelse` was going to work anyway.